# Converting column into proper timestamp using pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a time series csv file that consists of timestamps and financial data, like this:

```
20140804:10:00:13.281486,782.83,443355
20140804:10:00:13.400113,955.71,348603
```

Now, I would like to put this into a `pandas.DataFrame`, and parse the dates to `yyyymmddhhmmss` when I read in the `csv`.  I searched around the threads and I see people using the `datetime` module, but I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm not sure how to use that module to parse the above data, and to do this all at the same time I read in the `csv`.

How best to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

**no header of csv**:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""
20140804:10:00:13.281486,782.83,443355
20140804:10:00:13.400113,955.71,348603"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 #parse first columns 
                 parse_dates=[0], 
                 #custom parse function 
                 date_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S.%f'), 
                 #no header of csv
                 header=None) 

print (df)
                           0       1       2
0 2014-08-04 10:00:13.281486  782.83  443355
1 2014-08-04 10:00:13.400113  955.71  348603

print (df.dtypes)
0    datetime64[ns]
1           float64
2             int64
dtype: object
```

---

**header of csv**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""dates,a,b
20140804:10:00:13.281486,782.83,443355
20140804:10:00:13.400113,955.71,348603"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 parse_dates=[0], 
                 date_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S.%f'))

print (df)
                       dates       a       b
0 2014-08-04 10:00:13.281486  782.83  443355
1 2014-08-04 10:00:13.400113  955.71  348603     

print (df.dtypes)
dates    datetime64[ns]
a               float64
b                 int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you update your question? because problematic format of comments.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I now have the data in a form as shown above, but with the Timestamp as index.  I'd like to plot each column, a (asset_price), and b(units_traded) as a time series, so the timestamp being on the x-axis.  I've tried to use DataFrame.plot() but I'm getting timestamps that extend far beyond what is in my data, so it doesn't make sense; how would I plot such data as above as a time series?

Comment: Hard question, but it seems `matplotlib` manages it and create `axis` value between minimal and maximal value of index, maybe help convert index values to `strings` like `df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` and then call `df.plot()`